# three.js: performance drop on iPad beginning at 1024 pixels

Tags: performance, ipad, three.js, webkit

I have a website using `three.js` with `CanvasRenderer`. The renderer's size is set depending on the window size. On an iPad, the size is `1024 x 672` pixels. With this size, I get extremely bad performance (~1 FPS). If I reduce the width to `1023` Pixels, I get about 60 FPS.

Is there any specific reasion why the performance should drop significantly when hitting 1024 pixels? I don't have any issues with this resolution in Firefox.

Comment: That's interesting. However, only Apple can reply this question.

Comment: Thanks - although this isn't the answer I wanted to hear. Does three.js in any way use exactly one pixel more than set for the renderer? That would at least be an explanation, because it would be somewhat reasonable to optimize performance for things _up to_ 1024 pixels...

Comment: Did you try other resolutions like 1023 x 500??

Comment: Also, do you have have an example somewhere we can take a look?

Comment: I tried 1023 x 500, it's fast. As soon as one dimension hits 1024 pixels, I get bad performance. I'll see if I can build a short example...

Comment: OK, there already is a perfect example out there: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html In portrait mode, it is fine, in landscape, it becomes 1024 pixels wide, and performance drops.

Comment: felix it seems to be something in ipad itself. => http://forums.adobe.com/message/3418721#3418721 and keep in mind that the canvas renderer is always using antialiasing.

Comment: OH, thanks for that link. So I'll just add a small border, and hope it'll be fine.

Comment: After playing around a bit, I can confirm the same issue exists with Safari for Mac, too (1024 pixels trigger the issue, 1023 pixels don't). Firefox for Mac doesn't have the issue, and Safari for Windows works fine, too. Any more ideas?

Comment: It works fine one a first-generation iPad.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard about the HTML5 canvas element in some browsers losing a massive amount of performance once a certain number of pixels is being rendered. This would appear to be  caching issue with the browser itself. Though the question is still unanswered.

[Why does drawImage performance differ greatly with larger than 65776 pixel canvas sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038058/why-does-drawimage-performance-differ-greatly-with-larger-than-65776-pixel-canva)

Render the canvas at a lower resolution and use CSS to scale it up to full HD.