# Why does drawImage performance differ greatly with larger than 65776 pixel canvas sources

Tags: html, canvas, drawimage

I wrote some test cases on jsperf related to:
1. drawing on an offscreen canvas
2. drawImage to an onscreen canvas

I found that performance was much higher if the number of pixels in the source canvas (regardless of dst) was less than ~ 65776 pixels.

(I expected this performance limit to be 65536 pixels, if it was going to be anything)

Here are my test cases:
[image: jsperf results]
http://jsperf.com/pixel-count-matters/2

http://jsperf.com/magic-canvas/2

I believe this person is asking a similar question:
[Why does FPS go down if canvas is larger than 255x220?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366155/why-does-fps-go-down-if-canvas-is-larger-than-255x220/19037914#19037914)

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Likely has to do with buffer size. That one probably will require a source dive to find the actual answer.

Comment: i fear we cannot really know what's going on from the js code. Most likely, we have a 65536 L2 buffer + some small L1 cache that can do the caching job for the smaller image, and are overflowed by the larger one. To reduce measure noise i separated the line draw from the copy in http://jsperf.com/pixel-count-matters/3  and we can see that copy performances collapses even more than the post suggests (/100 !).

Comment: In your examples, you are drawing both tests to `c1`. You should test it again, with two different canvases for each case. Maybe it is related to the way the browsers initializes it's buffers.

Comment: `Testing in Chrome 38.0.2125.111 on Linux 64-bit` gives almost identical results... Previous versions of Chrome (37-) show differences like you've shown. Have they finally fixed this?

Comment: I see those results in the test. I tried to replicate, tested 38.0.2125.111 on OSX 10.8.5 and am still showing 100 ops vs. 150 ops.

Comment: Sebastien C. - the results do not differ with different canvases (you can look at rev4 if you want). When I initially worked on this problem I ruled out things like this out. The performance is commutative (order doesn't matter either).

Comment: I had a similar issue and tested it on 7 pcs with different configurations (single sceen, multiple screen, dedicated graphics, onboard graphics, etc...). It seams to have to do with how big one texture can be in the graphics card memory because Java2D tries to accelerate various stuff. My solution: detect the max resolution for high performance on target computert and scale up everything which should be bigger. Of course this looses sharpness, but for games it should be ok and less relevant than good performance. My 2 cents.